# How to hide form on submit button in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have created one absolutepanel in shiny. I have created on submit button and selectInput pane.

```
    selectInput("Customer", "Customer",groupcustomer),
            submitButton("Submit",icon("refresh"))
```

Above code is in div tag. I want to collapse i.e. hide particular div or hide form on submitButton. How can I do this?

Comment: As one of possible solutions: `observeEvent(input$Submit, shinyjs::runjs('$("#divToHide").toggle();')`)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I solve this as, HTML(paste('<span data-toggle="collapse" lass="btn btn-primary" data-target="#demo">',submitButton("Update View", icon("refresh")),'</span>'))

Comment: By the way, we can not use input$submit as submit is text in shiny, not a ID. We can not give ID to SubmitButton in shiny.

Comment: Post it as a sollution then and mark it correct when you can. Might help someone someday. Best to post as a complete working example too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will toggle hiding of the input form when the submit button is pushed:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- basicPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$div(id="hideme",
             selectInput("Customer", "Customer", c("bill","bob","bozo"))
             ),
    actionButton("doSubmit", "Submit", icon("refresh"),
                 style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$doSubmit, {
        toggle("hideme")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It replaces the submitButton with an actionButton as recommended in the help page and duplicates the style of submitButton.

> The use of submitButton is generally discouraged in favor of the more versatile actionButton (see details below).